# Help to select MOSFET gate driver

Tags: driver, pmos

I am implementing a system where I need to use 2 switches, 1 NMOS and another PMOS. The switches are controlled by a PWM wave that operates at a frequency of 1MHz.
You can see in the attached figure the current that is needed at each gate. The NMOS transistor is not critical and does not require a drive, but in the case of PMOS there is a need for a gate driver but I am not able to find any that consume little (max 2 / 3mW).[image]
Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you need a driver for the P-MOS unless there is a reason you didn't tell yet. Just make sure that its Gate voltage is equal to source voltage to turn it off.

Comment: Why would you use a pair of MOSFETs for such small current?